# Number of subproblems

Tags: algorithms

These are three paragraphs from the book CLRS:

> The rod-cutting problem is the following. Given a rod of length $n$
> inches and a table of prices $p_i$ for $i = 1, 2, ..., n$, determine
> the maximum revenue $r_n$ obtainable by cutting up the rod and selling
> the pieces.
>
> In the rod-cutting problem, an optimal solution for cutting up a rod
> of size $n$ uses just one subproblem (of size $n - i$), but we must
> consider $n$ choices for $i$ in order to determine which one yields an
> optimal solution.
>
> Informally, the running time of a dynamic-programming algorithm
> depends on the product of two factors: the number of subproblems
> overall and how many choices we look at for each subproblem. In rod
> cutting, we had $\Theta(n)$ subproblems overall, and at most $n$
> choices to examine for each, yielding an $\Theta(n^2)$ running time.

Now, how is it saying that the number of subproblems is $1$, in the second paragraph, and $\Theta(n)$, in the third paragraph? Do we have $1$ subproblem or $\Theta(n)$ subproblems? Maybe the third paragraph talks about the sum of products of subproblems by their sizes. I assume a subproblem(at least in this case) means the same problem but with an input size that is a nonconstant function of the input size of the original problem which is less than that input size. (I've read the other post about the definition of subproblem in the design and analysis of algorithms)

This is the recurrence relation for the problem and we want to solve it by dynamic programming:
$r_n = \text{max} (p_i + r_{n - i}) \;\;\;\;\; (1 \leq i \leq n)$

Comment: Do you believe that everyone has the book ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust No. I'll update my question with the definition of the rod-cutting problem.

Comment: The 2nd paragraph is talking about the structure of the optimal solution: the optimal way to cut a rod of length $n$ consists in cutting a piece of "the right" length $i$  (that won't be cut further) and then optimally cutting the remaining piece of length $n-i$. The value of the optimal solution for a rod of length $n$ only depends on the value of the optimal solution for this rod of length $n-i$ (once $i$ is known and the prices are fixed). The 3rd paragraph is talking about the overall number of subproblems you need to solve, i.e., $\Theta(n)$ corresponding all rod lengths up to $n$.

Comment: Define r_0 in the only sensible way, then calculate in that order r_1, r_2, r_3, ..., r_n.